bat file to extract string from one file and save the result in new file
I have bat file for example "config.bat" with many lines, like:
...
set var1=Y
set var2=N
set var5=True
...
rem Here you can set index variable
rem example set index=15
set index=30
...

I need a bat script who will take only the value "30" from "index" variable, and save it to another file, for example "indexnbr.txt". I can't call the "config.bat"
Thank you in advance!

By I can't call the "config.bat" do you mean that another batch script should read the contents of config.bat and extract the final value of index?

@AliKhan Yes, that's exactly what should happen.

This batch script should be able to filter config.bat for the statement where index is set and then it will write the corresponding value of index to the indexnbr.txt file:
@echo off
set config_file=config.bat

REM Extract the value of "index"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('findstr /N /R /C:"^set index=" "%config_file%"') do (
    >"indexnbr.txt" (echo %%A)
)

It leverages the findstr command to search for the statement where index is set, parses the result and then writes only the value of index to a file.
The tokens=2 delims== part in the script is for splitting the statement into parts based on the equals to symbol (the delimiter), and the second token is the value of index. Also, please note that the colon in /C: is MANDATORY for this to work, otherwise findstr's error handling will treat /C as an invalid option.


Hi @Ali Khan,
I saw that this script takes the values ​​of all variables, not just "index" and writes them to the output file. Since the "index" variable is not the last in the file, the result is incorrect and I get "Y" instead of "30"

@JordanHristov, thanks for pointing that out. I realized that spaces needed to be dealt with differently when using findstr. I've made an update to the answer.

Thank You @Ali Khan,
When I add /N /R /C: keys, еverything works as it should.

everything works, except you have 30   in indexnbr.txt, see space after 30. use (echo %%A)>"indexnbr.txt" or better >"indexnbr.txt" (echo %%A) to get rid of unwanted spaces

@elzooilogico, nice catch! I've updated the answer with the fix you suggested. Thanks!

What happens if the read file contains the line set index=?
